# android - two string not equals

Tags: android

im  using this code to get app is signed by me or not.

```
String SIGNATURE = "HmdQ7mF9uZ2unNb8qz1HEuD+iT4=";

    try {

        PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()

            .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(),

                            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

        for (Signature signature : packageInfo.signatures) {

            byte[] signatureBytes = signature.toByteArray();

            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");

            md.update(signature.toByteArray());

            final String currentSignature = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.d("1",currentSignature);
            Log.d("2",SIGNATURE);
            Log.d("equals:",
                  currentSignature.equals(SIGNATURE)?"true":"false");

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

logcat contains is:

```
1                                            HmdQ7mF9uZ2unNb8qz1HEuD+iT4=
2                                            HmdQ7mF9uZ2unNb8qz1HEuD+iT4=
equals                                       : false
```

strings is equals but logcat not say this!

whats problem?

Comment: Never catch an exception without handle it: `catch (Exception e) {
    }`

Comment: My guess is that there is whitespace, or something else, making the two strings not equal.

Comment: Use  `Log.d("1",">>"++currentSignature+"<<");` to see if there are leading or trailing not printable character

Comment: as Tim say, try using trim() `...currentSignature.trim().equals(SIGNATURE.trim())...`

Comment: @Yazan This will only works for spaches, not for other not printable character like EOL

Comment: @Jens correct, OP probably have to inspect values byte-level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
     if(currentSignature.trim().equals(SIGNATURE.trim()))
     {
        Log.d("TAG","equal");
     }
     else
     {
        Log.d("TAG","not equal");
     }
```